# C++ Run Batch file as standalone process and kill and remove argv[0]

Tags: c++, windows, batch-file, process

Let's imagine I have following code:

```
    ofstream selfdelfile;
    selfdelfile.open("selfdel.bat",ios::out);
    selfdelfile << "del \"" << argv[0] << "\"" << endl;
    selfdelfile << "del %0";
    selfdelfile.close();
    system("cmd /K selfdel.bat &");
```

C++ Application creates/writes file `selfdel.bat` with following lines

```
del "C:\Users\temp\test_app.exe" 
del %0
```

So, Batch should remove/delete the exe application, and itself.
So heres trouble: since C++ app runs batch by `system("selfdel.bat")` theres no way to delete exe application, the output says Process can't be terminated. Ofc, C++ app is waiting for batch, and batch cannot delete .exe. 
I was trying, to Kill process, delte file, e.t.c.
SO how to do that? May be Start a new Process or Thread? Could someone provide an simple example C++ runs Batch , and Batch removes itself + application. Thank you

Comment: The process of the executable you want to delete must be terminated before deleting it. That means that you'll have to run the batch file in some other process, possibly created by that of the executable.

Comment: Thank you for quick reply, but I found solution already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the working solution for me, just by adding "start" before batchfile

```
system("start selfdel.bat &");
```

Now batch opens in a new windows, and c++ application is getting closed and deleted.

Comment: That's actually it. Creating a new process.

Comment: That won't work reliably - it's a race condition.  If the application hasn't quite finished exiting when the batch file commands run, the batch file won't be able to delete the executable.  To fix that, put a loop in the batch file, i.e., have it check whether it was able to delete the file, and if not, try again.